# Matched set results relative to another selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Let's say I'm trying to retrieve elements who have an `active` child:

```
$('.a .active').parents('.a');
```

Is there a way to achieve this within the initial query, where you can specify the selector as one argument, and the selector for the result set as another argument?

Something like:

```
$('.a .active', '.a');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) in order to select `.a` elements that contain `.active` descendant elements:

```
$('.a:has(.active)');
```

---

It's worth pointing out that `$('.active', '.a')` is a [context selector](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) that will select `.active` elements that are descendants of `.a` elements.

In other words,

```
$('.active', '.a');
```

is essentially equivalent to:

```
$('.a').find('.active');
```

Both of the queries above would match the following:

```
<div class="a">
    <span class="active">This would be selected by both of the above.</span>
</div>
```

---

So the selector, `$('.a .active', '.a')`, would attempt to select `.active` descendant elements nested inside of an `.a` element and then in another `.a` element [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/fwf5rz9p/):

```
$('.a .active', '.a')
```

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="a">
        <span class="active">Select this.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Josh for the thorough explanation!